# Error "g++: CreateProcess: No such file or directory" when compiling Qt project

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, g++

I'm facing this classic G++ compiler error (MingW actually, since I'm in Windows) "CreateProcess: No such file or directory".

Classic as it is, there are many foruns and posts including here on SO with people reporting having this error and the symptoms, explanation and solution is basically always the same: the guy can't compile any code whatsoever and the fix is done by correcting the PATH environment variable by adding the directory where the compiler's files are. And the cause is normally the result of a problematic compiler installation.

My problem, though, is a little different: my installation is fine, so much so that I can successfully compile other projects (Qt projects specifically) using exactly the same compiler kit. The error only occurrs when I try to compile one specific Qt project which I haven't compile for some time. Unfortunately, the compiler/Qt don't give me any clue to why this specific project won't compile when others go on fine. Nevertheless I still checked my PATH env variable and the G++ files directory is there.

So what could be the cause of the problem? I checked my Qt .pro file for any 'special' stuff and everything was fine. Is good to notice I had already compiled this project in the pass, it's quite an old one already, and I don't remember ever facing this problem, nor any major changes in the .pro file was done recently.

(In case it helps:)

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to find the answer: poor programming.

This app is compilable for both Windows and Linux. In the Linux version, the team created a script that automatically gets the current SVN version and adds it to a variable inside the .pro:

```
DATE = $$system($${PWD}/../../get_compile_date.bat)
```

Then a define is created with the informed value:

```
DEFINES += COMPILE_DATE=\\\"$$DATE\\\"
```

Problem is, I'm compiling in Windows, so MinGW wasn't able to 'understand' the situation properly, leading to the error. Once the call to the script was removed, the problem went away.

```
DEFINES += COMPILE_DATE=\\\"03-03-2020\\\"
```